# Groupby data - show min and max dates and corresponding values

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have the following frame:

```
frame=pd.DataFrame(data=(['London','2020-08-31',3,4],['London','2020-09-30',1,5],
                         ['London','2020-10-31',2,6],['London','2020-11-30',7,3],
                         ['Paris','2020-08-31',9,3],['Paris','2020-09-30',1,8],
                         ['Paris','2020-10-31',4,5],['Paris','2020-11-30',2,9],
                         ['Paris','2020-12-31',3,8]),columns=["Location","Date","X","Y"])
```

it looks like that:

```
    Location    Date    X   Y
0   London  2020-08-31  3   4
1   London  2020-09-30  1   5
2   London  2020-10-31  2   6
3   London  2020-11-30  7   3
4   Paris   2020-08-31  9   3
5   Paris   2020-09-30  1   8
6   Paris   2020-10-31  4   5
7   Paris   2020-11-30  2   9
8   Paris   2020-12-31  3   8
```

I want to groupby Location and show the min and max dates and their corresponding values. Expected output is like that:

```
                                                   X                               Y    
Location    Min_Date    Max_Date    Min_Date_Value  Max_Date_Value  Min_Date_Value  Max_Date_Value
London      8/31/2020   11/30/2020        3               7                4              3
Paris       8/31/2020   12/31/2020        9               3                3              8
```

I can produce the min and max dates by `frame.groupby(by="Location")["Date"].agg(["min","max"])` but afterwards I struggle to visualize also the columns with corresponding values for each date.

Comment: try `frame.groupby(by="Location").agg(["min","max"])`

Comment: That would not give the values you expect though, it will select max and min for each column, and wouldnt correspond to max and min of dates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the below, if you want the aggregation on date and then pull corresponding rows:

```
u = frame.groupby(by="Location")["Date"].agg(["min","max"])
out = (u.stack().reset_index(name='Date').merge(frame)
       .set_index(['Location','level_1']).unstack())
out.columns = out.columns.map('_'.join)
```

---

```
print(out)

            Date_max    Date_min  X_max  X_min  Y_max  Y_min
Location                                                    
London    2020-11-30  2020-08-31      7      3      3      4
Paris     2020-12-31  2020-08-31      3      9      8      3
```

Comment: @MartinYordanovGeorgiev you can also try `frame.loc[frame.groupby(by="Location")["Date"].agg(["idxmin","idxmax"]).stack()]` if your date column is a datetime and take it from there :)